# How To get the Path rather then the filename in an xml file

Tags: python, xml, pandas, path

i want to modify this Python Code to Get The Full Path in my CSV rather then just the filename .

Here's the Code :

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (
                root.find('filename').text,
                int(member[4][0].text),
                int(member[4][1].text),
                int(member[4][2].text),
                int(member[4][3].text),
                member[0].text,
            )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax', 'class']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'annotations')
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
    xml_df.to_csv('Covnverted.csv', index=None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

In My Output , the CSV file Should Look Something like This :

/Users/Midji/Desktop/CV/Code/Project1/logos/images/452893.jpg,334,177,1035,716,CocaCola
/Users/Midji/Desktop/CV/Code/Project1/logos/images/409261.jpg,446,267,503,310,CocaCola

.

.

.

PS : For Exemple My First XML is Structured This Way :

```
 <annotation>
<folder>VOC2007</folder>
<filename>im_fn</filename>
<source>
    <database>ROMYNY Database</database>
    <annotation>ROMYNY Annotation</annotation>
    <image>Unspecified</image>
</source>
<owner>
    <name>Unspecified</name>
</owner>
<size>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>CocaCola</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>1</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>334</xmin>
        <ymin>177</ymin>
        <xmax>1035</xmax>
        <ymax>716</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

Any Help Would be Much Appreciated , Thank you

Comment: Can you give what you have in your XML input file ?

Comment: Please try to replace lines 'value = (root.find('filename').text,' with 'value = (xml_file,'

Comment: @GeofoxCoding , I tried , the thing is , i get an empty CSV file !!!! , there is just the name of the columns

Comment: @DouL Ok you want the path of an image not of the xml you are currently parsing. How is the logic to get the path for objects image? If filename contains something like "im_fn" and you want a path like ".../452893.jpg" where is the relation? Where are your images located and how to you relate to the object in xml?

Comment: When you do `root.find('filename').text` in your script, what you get from your input is `im_fn`. I see you also have the folder name, is what you want is to search in your files the absolute path of the file `im_fn` in the directory `VOC2007` ?